# Set font face and size in Scala TextArea

Tags: swing, scala

An old thread (2009) mentioned the following:

```
val area = new TextArea {
   font = new Font("Arial", 0, 8)
}
```

However that code has no effect on current version of `scala.swing`  . I also tried

```
area.peer.setFont(new Font("Arial", 0,8).
```

That also had no effect. So what is the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
  val area = new TextArea
  area.setFont(new Font("Arial", 0, 8))
```

Comment: ugh I had been setting the font in the container instead of on the TextArea itself. it does work either your way or as my original code.

Comment: yes i said either way is ok : my original code or yours. I just put it on the wrong component.